# Unable to Redirect Query String with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a URL with www.example.com/info/users?lookup=some-info and I need to change all such URLs to www.example.com/info/some-info. I am doing this as under, I am sorry as I very much bad in .htaccess :(

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lookup=([^&]+)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^info\users/$ /info/%1? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^info\users^` – that needs to be a forward slash, and anchoring to the end of the subject in regular expressions is done via the `$` sign, not `^`.

Comment: something like this? RewriteRule ^info\users/$ /info/%1? [L,R=301,NC]

Comment: That’s still a backslash in your path. And if the requested path doesn’t end with a forward slash, then you should not start demanding one now.

Comment: You should not edit your question so that it does not show the initial problem any more, that will just make it lose all value for future readers (I rolled back that edit). If you want to mark this as solved, then you can write an answer explaining what the problem was and how it was solved yourself.

Comment: Yes CBrore, Agreed and It was the final solution, need to do this in second line,   RewriteRule ^info\users^ /info/%1? [L,R=301,NC]